Java encrypt a zip file then decrypt with openssl
The  goal is to be able to encrypt a Zip file in Java, and decrypt it elsewhere using openssl or Python.
I use the following to (hopefully) encrypt a ZIP file in Java, cobbled together from a couple of other Stack Overflow posts.
      try{

         String salt = "MySalt";
         String secretKey = "__hello123__world123__again123__ ";
         File zipFile = new File("input.zip");
         byte[] indata = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(zipFile.toPath());
         SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
         byte[] iv = new byte[16];
         secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
         IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

         SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
         KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
         SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
         SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivspec);

         byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(indata);
         byte[] encryptedData = new byte[iv.length + cipherText.length];
         System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedData, 0, iv.length);
         System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, encryptedData, iv.length, cipherText.length);

         String b64DecData =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedData);

         try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipName+".enc", "UTF-8")) {
               outputStream.write(b64DecData.getBytes());
         }


      }catch(Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
      }
 

The input zip file starts with:
od -c input.zip | head
0000000   P   K 003 004 024  \0  \b  \b  \b  \0 331 276 216   X  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 006  \0  \0  \0   u   m

The output encrypt zip file starts with:
od -c input.zip.enc | head
0000000   n   L   4   s   T   E   L   W   8   i   V   M   2   J   m   X
0000020   0   a   z   U   r   x   a   W   e   J   E   z   G   C   c   2
0000040   9   t   7   L   E   2   u   O   A   E   s   n   p   B   L   e
0000060   r   a   s   n   Q   F   2   u   +   +   i   e   N   v   x   H
0000100   j   F   A   u   0   O   G   Y   z   d   /   P   n   G   k   s
0000120   L   U   Y   e   D   5   h   q   D   C   I   F   b   R   Z   g

To reverse (decypt) this I am using a shell script as follows:

base64 -d  input.zip.enc > dec1

salt=$( echo -n MySalt | od -A n -t x1 | perl -lpe's,\s+,,g' )

iv=$( head -c16 dec1 | xxd -p ) 

echo 'IV is [' $iv ']'
echo 'Salt is [' $salt ']'

( printf Salted__MySalt; tail -c+17 dec1 ) > dec2

openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k __hello123__world123__again123__ -pbkdf2 -iter 65536 -iv $iv -in dec2 -out dec.zip
echo

When I run this I get an error:

IV is [ 9cbe2c4c42d6f2254cd89997d1acd4af ]
Salt is [ 4d7953616c74 ]
bad decrypt
80AB5872277A0000:error:1C80006B:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_generic_block_final:wrong final block length:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon.c:429:

It produces file of a similar to to the original, but not the same as the decrypted zip file is corrupt:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx   81695 Apr 14 23:54 input.zip      ### Input
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx  108952 Apr 14 23:54 input.zip.enc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx   81710 Apr 15 00:32 dec2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx   81712 Apr 15 00:32 dec1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx   81680 Apr 15 00:32 dec.zip        ### Output should = input.zip

Although the file sizes of input.zip almost = size of dec.zip the contents are very different:
od -c dec1.zip | head
od -c dec.zip | head
0000000 272 205 233 001 315   B 003 353   B   = 257 366 306 214 227   u
0000020   f 372 377   < 214   x 260 256   W 312   { 276 300 271   d   }
0000040   4   6 326 227 345 305 022   > 205  \v  \b 232  \r   %  \v 206


I expected the base64 decode is not right, but I'm really not sure.
The openssl version is:
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

You don't need to read the entire file into memory in the Java code. Have a look at CipherOutputStream and Base64$Encoder.wrap().

As I said in my answer to your previous question, you must use -saltlen 6 and it only works on OpenSSL >= 3.2.0. 3.0.2 is NOT >= 3.2.0.
